# pygments highlight print in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, lexer, pygments

I would like to print a string with sql into my jupyter notebook like below
[image]

This was done manually with pygments, [see](https://pygments.org/demo/?lexer=sql&style=default&formatter=html&code=SELECT%0A%20%20%20*%0AFROM%0A%20%20%20latest.tmp)

Here is what I tried so far

```
from pygments import highlight
from pygments.lexers import SqlLexer
from pygments.formatters import HtmlFormatter
from IPython.core.display import HTML, display
query = '''
SELECT
   *
FROM
   latest.tmp
'''
display(HTML(highlight(query, SqlLexer(), HtmlFormatter())))
```

In the output keywords are neither green nor bold. (I am using Jupyterlab.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to also set `HtmlFormatter(full=True)`

[image]